# Python ex_setup.py urlopen error [Errno 11004] getaddrinfo failed

Tags: python, windows, installation, setuptools

I just installed Python on Windows 7 as described on 
http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/1.4-branch/narr/install.html.
Im at step 3 and get the following error when I run the python ez_setup.py command.
I go the ez_setup.py from this URL http://peak.telecommunity.com/dist/ez_setup.py

```
c:\Python27>python ez_setup.py
Downloading http://pypi.python.org/packages/2.7/s/setuptools/setuptools-0.6c11-p
y2.7.egg
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ez_setup.py", line 278, in <module>
    main(sys.argv[1:])
  File "ez_setup.py", line 210, in main
    egg = download_setuptools(version, delay=0)
  File "ez_setup.py", line 158, in download_setuptools
    src = urllib2.urlopen(url)
  File "c:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 126, in urlopen
    return _opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "c:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 400, in open
    response = self._open(req, data)
  File "c:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 418, in _open
    '_open', req)
  File "c:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 378, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "c:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 1207, in http_open
    return self.do_open(httplib.HTTPConnection, req)
  File "c:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 1177, in do_open
    raise URLError(err)
urllib2.URLError: <urlopen error [Errno 11004] getaddrinfo failed>

c:\Python27>
```

Comment: I found issue to the problem.
It was due to a network proxy which can be fixed with the following command.
`set http_proxy=user:password@proxyaddress:port`.
I hope this helps someone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is in the comment above.

When you are behind a proxy, there is an Windows environment variable which is used to store the proxy setting.

That variable is `http_proxy` and for secure `https_proxy`.

The format of setting this variable is below

```
set http_proxy=user:password@proxyaddress:port
set https_proxy=user:password@proxyaddress:port
```

If there is no password, then do the following

```
set http_proxy=user@proxyaddress:port
```

So an example would be

```
set http_proxy=jbrown:jbpass@192.168.0.252:8080
```