# Grabbing Image off Website Error

Tags: pycharm, urllib, python-3.4

I just started learning Python and I followed [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GQiLweAoxgQ&index=23&list=PL6gx4Cwl9DGAcbMi1sH6oAMk4JHw91mC_) tutorial to download a picture from a website. It is a very simple code and I get an error as shown below. Does anybody know why I get this error? Something this simple is driving me insane.

I am using PyCharm 4.5.3 and have Python 3.4.

My code:

```
import random
import urllib.request


def download_web_image(url):
    name = random.randrange(1, 1000)
    full_name = str(name) + ".jpg"
    urllib.request.urlretrieve(url, full_name)

download_web_image("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/5/51/Name.jpeg")
```

My error

```
C:\Python34\python.exe D:/Users/212409097/PycharmProjects/HTTP_Server/Example.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\lib\urllib\request.py", line 1182, in do_open
    h.request(req.get_method(), req.selector, req.data, headers)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\http\client.py", line 1088, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\http\client.py", line 1126, in _send_request
    self.endheaders(body)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\http\client.py", line 1084, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\http\client.py", line 922, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\http\client.py", line 857, in send
    self.connect()
  File "C:\Python34\lib\http\client.py", line 1223, in connect
    super().connect()
  File "C:\Python34\lib\http\client.py", line 834, in connect
    self.timeout, self.source_address)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\socket.py", line 494, in create_connection
    for res in getaddrinfo(host, port, 0, SOCK_STREAM):
  File "C:\Python34\lib\socket.py", line 533, in getaddrinfo
    for res in _socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, type, proto, flags):
socket.gaierror: [Errno 11004] getaddrinfo failed

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/Users/212409097/PycharmProjects/HTTP_Server/Example.py", line 10, in <module>
    download_web_image("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/5/51/Name.jpeg")
  File "D:/Users/212409097/PycharmProjects/HTTP_Server/Example.py", line 8, in download_web_image
    urllib.request.urlretrieve(url, full_name)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\urllib\request.py", line 186, in urlretrieve
    with contextlib.closing(urlopen(url, data)) as fp:
  File "C:\Python34\lib\urllib\request.py", line 161, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\urllib\request.py", line 463, in open
    response = self._open(req, data)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\urllib\request.py", line 481, in _open
    '_open', req)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\urllib\request.py", line 441, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\urllib\request.py", line 1225, in https_open
    context=self._context, check_hostname=self._check_hostname)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\urllib\request.py", line 1184, in do_open
    raise URLError(err)
urllib.error.URLError: <urlopen error [Errno 11004] getaddrinfo failed>

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error generally occurs when a user is behind a firewall. Most of the common solutions to this problem can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5022945/urllib2-urlerror-urlopen-error-errno-11004-getaddrinfo-failed/16904232#16904232). Let us know if none of these solve your problem!

#### Things I'd try first:

1. Disabling any active firewalls and try a different internet source if you're at your employer or a wifi hotspot.
2. If you're using a proxy, you can handle that in urllib, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4847649/opening-websites-using-urllib2-from-behind-corporate-firewall-11004-getaddrinf)
3. If it still persists, maybe try the second answer from that question, [setting the system variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25917357/python-ex-setup-py-urlopen-error-errno-11004-getaddrinfo-failed).
4. Possibly try to recreate your code in a clean environment.

I was able to download the image in PyCharm using your above code without problems, leading me to think you have a firewall issue. Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you very much. I am behind an employer firewall. I will try some of these options.